Changing just the name of the django settings file causes error
I ran into a problem trying originally to use cookiecutter-django when using the docker compose production.yml vs the local.yml files
Managed to shrink it down to this: https://github.com/xmclej/django-testing-01
The code is currently defaulted to use "config.settings.base"
See the README.md file for the very minimal setup and instructions
The problem is that when I change only the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE value from "config.settings.base" to "config.settings.trial". Noting that the two files are identical inside.
Get error..

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings.trial'

Any thoughts? Originally was trying to use the default cookiecuttter approach of split settings files. Until I hit this little bug.
Using config.settings.base ... it works
(venv) D:\Beanycode\Projects\django-testing-01>docker compose -f production.yml up
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container django-testing-01-postgres-1  Running                                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container django-testing-01-django-1    Recreated                                                                                   0.1s 
Attaching to django-1, postgres-1
django-1    | PostgreSQL is available
django-1    | start of production entrypoint
django-1    | django
django-1    | /app
django-1    | 10
django-1    | 20
django-1    | 30
django-1    | 50
django-1    | 60
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:37:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:37:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:37:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:37:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:37:23 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:37:23 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:37:23 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
django-1    | BASE DIR is  /app
django-1    | BASE DIR is  /app
django-1    | BASE DIR is  /app
django-1    | BASE DIR is  /app

Using config.settings.trial ... it does not???
(venv) D:\Beanycode\Projects\django-testing-01>docker compose -f production.yml up
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container django-testing-01-postgres-1  Created                                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container django-testing-01-django-1    Recreated                                                                                   0.1s 
Attaching to django-1, postgres-1
postgres-1  | 
postgres-1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres-1  |
postgres-1  | 2024-05-14 23:38:44.809 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.6 (Debian 15.6-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres-1  | 2024-05-14 23:38:44.809 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres-1  | 2024-05-14 23:38:44.809 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres-1  | 2024-05-14 23:38:44.816 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-1  | 2024-05-14 23:38:44.825 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-05-14 23:38:33 UTC
postgres-1  | 2024-05-14 23:38:44.833 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
django-1    | PostgreSQL is available
django-1    | start of production entrypoint
django-1    | django
django-1    | /app
django-1    | 10
django-1    | 20
django-1    | 30
django-1    | 50
django-1    | 60
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:45 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:45 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:45 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:45 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
django-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
django-1    |     worker.init_process()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
django-1    |     self.load_wsgi()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
django-1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
django-1    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
django-1    |     self.callable = self.load()
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
django-1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
django-1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
django-1    |   File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
django-1    |     application = get_wsgi_application()
django-1    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django-1    |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
django-1    |     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
django-1    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
django-1    |     self._setup(name)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
django-1    |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings.trial'
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
django-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
django-1    |     worker.init_process()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
django-1    |     self.load_wsgi()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
django-1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
django-1    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
django-1    |     self.callable = self.load()
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
django-1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
django-1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
django-1    |   File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
django-1    |     application = get_wsgi_application()
django-1    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django-1    |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
django-1    |     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
django-1    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
django-1    |     self._setup(name)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
django-1    |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings.trial'
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) exited with code 3
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) was sent SIGTERM!
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
django-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
django-1    |     worker.init_process()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
django-1    |     self.load_wsgi()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
django-1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
django-1    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
django-1    |     self.callable = self.load()
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
django-1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
django-1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
django-1    |   File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
django-1    |     application = get_wsgi_application()
django-1    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django-1    |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
django-1    |     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
django-1    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
django-1    |     self._setup(name)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
django-1    |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings.trial'
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
django-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
django-1    |     worker.init_process()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
django-1    |     self.load_wsgi()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
django-1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
django-1    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
django-1    |     self.callable = self.load()
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
django-1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
django-1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
django-1    |   File "/app/config/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
django-1    |     application = get_wsgi_application()
django-1    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django-1    |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
django-1    |     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
django-1    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
django-1    |     self._setup(name)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
django-1    |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
django-1    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
django-1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
django-1    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
django-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django-1    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
django-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django-1    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings.trial'
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
django-1    | [2024-05-14 23:38:46 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:11) exited with code 3
django-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
django-1    |     self.sleep()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
django-1    |     ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
django-1    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
django-1    |     self.reap_workers()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
django-1    |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
django-1    | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
django-1    |
django-1    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django-1    |
django-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
django-1    |     sys.exit(run())
django-1    |              ^^^^^
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
django-1    |     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236, in run
django-1    |     super().run()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
django-1    |     Arbiter(self).run()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
django-1    |     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
django-1    |     self.stop()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 396, in stop
django-1    |     time.sleep(0.1)
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
django-1    |     self.reap_workers()
django-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
django-1    |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
django-1    | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
django-1 exited with code 1

